# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have made a guess the number program in Python 3.6,here is my code.

```
import random
guesses = 0
print('Hello! What is your name?')
name = input()
num = random.randint(1,10)
print('well',name,'I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20.')
while guesses < 4:
    print('Take a guess.')  
    guess = input()
    guess = int(guess)
    guesses = guesses + 1

    if guess < num:
        print('Your guess is too low.')

    if guess > num:
             print('Your guess is too high.')
    if guess == num:
        guesses = str(guessesTaken)
        print('Good job, ',name,'! You guessed my number in ',guesses,' guesses!')

    if guess != num:
         num = str(num)
         print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was ',num)
```

When I run my code it shows this error message

```
Hello! What is your name?
h
well h I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20.
Take a guess.
7
Your guess is too low.
Nope. The number I was thinking of was  10
Take a guess.
5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Number game.py", line 13, in <module>
    if guess < num:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

Why does it support > but not < ?
All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python the `print` function will happily convert objects to strings, you do not need to do it.  In the case of this code, your attempt to convert objects to strings prior to printing, ruined the variables for later use. So, just remove these two lines, and your code seems to work fine:

```
guesses = str(guessesTaken)

num = str(num)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.